# Handle Mouse Click in a AutoComplete Combobox in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I have a ComboBox control in C# Windows forms project. I have set the **DropDownStyle** of the control to **DropDown** and have also configured **AutoComplete** properties to the control. This is working well.

On this control, I have a requirement when I press Enter after selecting a value, it should fire a button click. For this, I handled the keyDown event and checked `if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)` which works well.

The problem is the following -

When I start typing the AutoComplete box opens up for the control and if I select one of them from mouse, the KeyDown event is fired and the system thinks that an "Enter" key is pressed.

**CODE**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }

    private void cb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            button1_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

**BEHAVIOR**

[image]

**I type B from keyboard and clicked on "B2" and got the alert.**

Any ideas on what could be the issue? Happy to share more details if required.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `KeyDown` event will not be raised when you click using mouse. You have got something wrong. Post a [short but complete sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Added code. please check now.

Comment: Interesting. I can reproduce the problem. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Glad you're able to reproduce. Any pointers will be of great help.

Comment: I tried to suppress the event in this case.It gets tricky. WM_KeyDown message is received, not sure that's the expected behavior; Lets see if someone with win32 knowledge can come with an explanation.